# ORA-13249: SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-spatial

I get an error when I run the following Sql Script in ORACLE

```
SELECT D.ID
FROM  DOOR D
JOIN STREET S ON (S.ID=D.STREET_ID)
WHERE 
SDO_NN(D.LOCATION,SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POINT (11112.0111 321314.2222)'),'sdo_num_res=6') = 'TRUE'
or 
S.ID IN (17);
```

but when I change '**or**' to '**and**' or  delete '**or S.ID IN (17)**' I get no error.

```
SELECT D.ID
FROM  DOOR D
JOIN STREET S ON (S.ID=D.STREET_ID)
WHERE 
SDO_NN(D.LOCATION,SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POINT (11112.0111 321314.2222)'),'sdo_num_res=6') = 'TRUE'
and 
S.ID IN (17);
```

Type of **Location** field in **DOOR** Table is **MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY**

and

Type of **ID** field in **STREET** Table is **NUMBER**

**I want first SQL to work.**
Can anyone help with the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would hint do any good?

```
SELECT /*+ LEADING(d) USE_NL(d s) INDEX s spatial_index) */
       D.ID
  FROM DOOR D JOIN STREET S ON (S.ID = D.STREET_ID)
 WHERE     SDO_NN (
              D.LOCATION,
              SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY ('POINT (11112.0111 321314.2222)'),
              'sdo_num_res=6') =
           'TRUE'
       AND S.ID IN (17);
```

Comment: query still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the **SDO_NN** operator (as opposed to the **SDO_RELATE** or **SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE** operators) can only be solved via a spatial index.

With the first query, no actual filter is applied to select from the DOOR table, so the query optimizer naturally uses the spatial index.

With the second query, you restrict the DOOR table to only those rows (doors) for a given street (STREET.ID=17). That makes the optimizer choose the index that applies that filter (probably the index on STREET.STREET_ID.

The **or** vs **and** makes for a very different query and a very different result. With **or**, you are asking for the 6 closest doors to the selected point, from **any** street + **all** the doors on **street 17** irrespective of proximity.

With **and** you are asking for the **6 closest doors on street 17** only. Which makes much more sense than the first syntax.

In order to make that work in your case, you need to use a hint to tell the optimizer to use the spatial index instead of the index on DOOR.STREET_ID:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX (d <spatial index name>) */ D.ID
FROM DOOR D
JOIN STREET S ON (S.ID=D.STREET_ID)
WHERE SDO_NN(D.LOCATION,SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POINT (11112.0111 321314.2222)'),'sdo_num_res=6') = 'TRUE'
AND S.ID IN (17);
```

Notice the syntax of the hint: `d` refers to the alias that refers to the DOOR table, since this is the one you are doing the spatial filtering on. `<spatial index name>` is the name of the spatial index you have defined on the DOOR table (not the string "spatial_index".

Hints have a "fragile" syntax: if you make any mistake, the hint will just be ignored. Also they are not **orders** to the optimizer: they are just **suggestions**. If the optimizer finds a hint impossible to apply (like you ask for an index that does not exist), it will also ignore it.

One way to confirm that hints have been accepted and used by the optimizer is to look at the query plan it has produced. If you use sqlplus or sqlcl, you can use the `EXPLAIN PLAN` command that will show you the plan without actually executing the statement. If you use SQLDeveloper, that has specific buttons to show query plans.

**EDIT:** The `INDEX` hint might not be sufficient. It may be that the optimizer needs to be told also how to implement the join, as @littlefoot has indicated. So you may also need the `LEADING` and `USE_NL` hints. But try first with only the `INDEX` hint.

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work.

Comment: Hints can be hard to tame. Are you sure you are using the correct name of the spatial index in the hint ?

Comment: Is it possible to share the data and tables you are using, or at least a subset ?